# Convenient way to pass package options and \setup like commands

Tags: starred-version, package-options, french

I want to be organized in my code. In order to pass options to packages, i developped my own macros :

```
\makeatletter

\newcommand*\Option{%
  \@ifstar{\@Option}{}}

\newcommand*\@Option[3]{%
  \PassOptionsToPackage{#2}{#1}}

\makeatother
```

One example of use, in preamble:

```
\Option*{babel}{frenchb}{french babel language}
```

#1 is the package name
#2 is the option 
#3 is a short description 
The star indicates that we effectively want to use the option. 
The package name is the first argument so that i can sort them alphabetically.

The starred version works. But the unstarred version, code:

```
\Option{babel}{frenchb}{french babel language}
```

produces the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}
```

To go further with the frenchb package, frenchb provides a command to globally change the aspect of the document : \frenchbsetup{}

I want to manage that the same way:

```
\makeatletter

\newcommand*\Frenchb{%
  \@ifstar{\@Frenchb}{}}

\newcommand*\@Frenchb[2]{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \@ifpackagewith{babel}{frenchb}
     {\frenchbsetup{#1}}
     {}}}

\makeatother
```

The starred version doesn't work, and the unstarred version produces the same error as \Option.

---

Here is the full document:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\Option{%
  \@ifstar{\@Option}{}}

\newcommand*\@Option[3]{%
  \PassOptionsToPackage{#2}{#1}}

\newcommand*\Frenchb{%
  \@ifstar{\@Frenchb}{}}

\newcommand*\@Frenchb[2]{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \@ifpackagewith{babel}{frenchb}
     {\frenchbsetup{#1}}
     {}}}

\makeatother

\Option{babel}{frenchb}        {french babel language}
\Frenchb{CompactItemize=false} {don't make compact itemize}

\usepackage{babel}
%\frenchbsetup{CompactItemize=false}

\begin{document}

  \part{Introduction} % checking babel/frenchb

    \begin{itemize} % checking CompactItemize=false
      \item item 1
      \item item 2
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the no `*` case you do nothing which leaves the following arguments as text in the input stream which is not allowed before `\begin{document}` (and you do not want to typeset the text anyway) so you have to gobble three and two arguments respectively:

```
\makeatletter
\def\eat@Option#1#2#3{}
\newcommand*\Option{%
  \@ifstar{\@Option}{\eat@Option}}

\newcommand*\@Option[3]{%
  \PassOptionsToPackage{#2}{#1}}

\newcommand*\Frenchb{%
  \@ifstar{\@Frenchb}{\@gobbletwo}}

\newcommand*\@Frenchb[2]{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \@ifpackagewith{babel}{frenchb}
     {\frenchbsetup{#1}}
     {}}}
```